# JavaScript fails to apply certain `.class` to a specific `span id=` - why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a JavaScript which, when `<a class="hint-button"` is clicked, should apply `.blur-filter-off` class **only** to that part of the text which is *inside* the `<span id="hint-ru">` and `<span id="hint-en">`.
In my example the text "This is" and "Das ist" should become unblurred, the rest of the text - should stay blurred (because of the `.blur-filter-on` class initially applied to it) .
However, my code doesn't work. [Here](https://jsbin.com/habelubiko/edit?html,css,js,output) is the JS Bin, where I also saved my code.

```js
function showHint(hintRuId, hintEnId) {
  // Get the hint spans by their IDs
  const hintRu = document.getElementById(hintRuId);
  const hintEn = document.getElementById(hintEnId);

  // Toggle the blur-filter-off class for the hint spans
  if (hintRu) hintRu.classList.toggle("blur-filter-off");
  if (hintEn) hintEn.classList.toggle("blur-filter-off");
}
```

```css
.quote,
.quote-en {
  font-family: Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.quote {
  color: #1f2c60;
  text-shadow: 0.04em 0.04em 0.06em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 6vw 2vw 6vw 2vw;
  font-size: calc(1em + 2.5vw);
}

.quote-en {
  color: #5d78e5;
  margin: 0vw 2vw 2vw 2vw;
  font-size: calc(0.2em + 2.5vw);
}

.hint-button {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 7%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 3.4em;
  width: 3.4em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0.07em 0px 0px #f29c93;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fe1a00 5%, #ce0100 100%);
  border: 0.05em solid #d83526;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 0.1em;
  text-shadow: 0px 0.05em 0px #b23e35;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.hint-button::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #f2eb08;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(0.001);
}

.hint-button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.hint-button:focus::before {
  animation: hint-button-click 0.6s ease-out;
}

.blur-filter-on {
  filter: blur(0.35em);
}

.blur-filter-off {
  animation-name: blur-decrease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  filter: blur(0);
}

@keyframes blur-decrease {
  from {
    filter: blur(0.35em);
  }
  to {
    filter: blur(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <span class="blur-filter-on">“<span id="hint-ru">This is</span>&nbsp;the example of text”</span>
</div>
<div class="quote-en">
  <span class="blur-filter-on">“<span id="hint-en">Das ist</span>&nbsp;the example of text”</span>
</div>

<a class="hint-button" href="#" onclick="showHint('hint-ru', 'hint-en')">HINT</a>
```

Comment: blur is on the parent, not the children

Comment: You are trying to remove the blur on a child. Since the parent is still blurred, it will be still be blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap all the text inside other elements (e.g. `span`) and apply the filter to all children (instead of the container).

```js
function showHint(hintRuId, hintEnId) {
  const hintRu = document.getElementById(hintRuId);
  const hintEn = document.getElementById(hintEnId);
  if (hintRu) hintRu.classList.toggle("blur-filter-off");
  if (hintEn) hintEn.classList.toggle("blur-filter-off");
}
```

```css
.blur-filter-on > * {
  filter: blur(0.35em);
}

.quote,.quote-en{font-family:Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif;text-align:center;overflow-wrap:break-word}.quote{color:#1f2c60;text-shadow:.04em .04em .06em rgba(0,0,0,.3);margin:6vw 2vw;font-size:calc(1em + 2.5vw)}.quote-en{color:#5d78e5;margin:0 2vw 2vw;font-size:calc(.2em + 2.5vw)}.hint-button{display:flex;position:fixed;bottom:7%;left:50%;transform:translateX(-50%);justify-content:center;align-items:center;text-decoration:none;height:3.4em;width:3.4em;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;box-shadow:inset 0 .07em 0 0 #f29c93;background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#fe1a00 5%,#ce0100 100%);border:.05em solid #d83526;border-radius:50%;color:#fff;font-weight:700;padding:.1em;text-shadow:0 .05em 0 #b23e35;font-size:3vw}.hint-button::before{content:'';background-color:#f2eb08;border-radius:50%;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;transform:scale(.001)}.hint-button:focus{outline:0;color:#fff}.hint-button:focus::before{animation:.6s ease-out hint-button-click}.blur-filter-off{animation-name:blur-decrease;animation-timing-function:ease;animation-duration:1s;filter:blur(0)}@keyframes blur-decrease{from{filter:blur(.35em)}to{filter:blur(0)}}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <span class="blur-filter-on"><span>“</span><span id="hint-ru">This is</span><span>&nbsp;the example of text”</span></span>
</div>
<div class="quote-en">
  <span class="blur-filter-on"><span>“</span><span id="hint-en">Das ist</span><span>&nbsp;the example of text”</span></span>
</div>

<a class="hint-button" href="#" onclick="showHint('hint-ru', 'hint-en')">HINT</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! However, this solution doesn't allow to apply `blur-filter-on` to _other_ elements, since in your version it works **only** for children elements. I made another JS Bin (https://jsbin.com/voliriritu/edit?html,css,js,output) where the `blur-filter-on` is applied to the `<div class="bio">`, but it doesn't work.
Important is, that `<div class="bio">` should **not** change/unblur on a button click. But currently it is not _initially_ blurred as intended either. :(

Comment: @Shakalakah You could move the `blur-filter-on` class to the `<div class="bio">` element: https://jsfiddle.net/rxu89pdq/ Also, you can use `.blur-filter-on :not(.blur-filter-off)` to target descendant elements including non-direct children.